# How can I accomplish the automatic execution of many scripts on many databases in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, automation, oracle-sqldeveloper

Some Sprints we need to take many (sometimes 20+) different P-SQL Scripts and execute all of them on multiple Databases (dev,test,demo,etc...).

I need to automate this or else I'll go insane.

I tried creating a Job, but It doesn't seem to work like I want it to. My idea was to let it point to the (local) repo/folder where the scripts are and run them for each Database.

Using SQL Developer for this Task is no priority, but it would be nice if I could make it work without using some other software.

Comment: You can create .bat or .sh scripts to execute all the db scripts and then use OS scheduler to achieve the task

Comment: We don't have multi-database execution feature today but we're looking to build it for a future release.

Comment: Thanks, I'll handle each Database separately via Powershell then.

Comment: @FullStackDAU How many databases do you have?  I built an [open source program](https://github.com/method5/method5) exactly for this kind of situation, and it works in SQL Developer.  The downside is that there's a non-trivial amount of work required to set it up and administer it.  If you have 400 databases it can be a life-saver, but if you only have 4 databases it's probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now settled for a PowerShell Script using SqlPlus. 
For anyone interested, this is the Tutorial I used to make it work: https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-run-sql-queries-using-sqlplus